# laravel new blog don't work

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

i m trying to creat a new project with laravel 5.1 and i m using composer 1.0.0 but try to creat a new project with this commande

```
 laravel new testhere
```

i get this error

```
  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException] 
  TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.
```

and whene i try this

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

i get this error

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
```

and it's tell me that xdebeug is enable

Answer (score 3):

**Solved:**

do the following:

**1: composer global require "laravel/installer"**

**2: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog**